# Add Preset Percentage in Power BI Visual

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a log of worker time spent throughout a workday, and have a visual that shows how their time is spent as a percentage of their day. However, the workers do not log "allowance" times, such as 10% for pre-job planning, and 5% for admin (discussions with supervisor, timesheets, etc). Is there a way to include these percentages without going back and "creating" data?

Thank you!

[image: Sample data]

[image: Sample visualization]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but you'd need to modify your data model slightly.

Start by creating a new table that will hold all the values of the [Activity] column, along with the 2 new "virtual" items for which you don't have any actual data:

```
Activity = UNION(DISTINCT(Timesheet[Activity]), {"Pre-job planning", "Admin"})
```

Here, I'm assuming that the table we see in your screenshot is called `Timesheet`.

Then, create a relationship between the new `Activity` table and the `Timesheet[Activity]`-column on your TimeSheet table. Hide the `[Activity]` column on your `Timesheet` table. Modify your visuals so that they use the new `Activity` table instead for slicing the data.

So far, you won't see any difference.

Now you create a new measure [Total Hours] using the following DAX:

```
Total Hours =
SUMX(
    VALUES(Activity[Activity]),
    SWITCH(Activity[Activity],
        "Pre-job planning", SUM(Timesheet[Hours]) * 0.1,
        "Admin", SUM(Timesheet[Hours]) * 0.05,
        CALCULATE(SUM(Timesheet[Hours]))
    )
)
```

Use this measure in all your visuals, instead of the [Hours] column, and things should magically work. Even the total should correctly be increased by 15 %.